# Angular: router-relead because of query-parameters

Tags: angular

I have router-links that point to the same component but have different parameters.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/goto']" [queryParams]="{mode: '1'}">Goto1</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/goto']" [queryParams]="{mode: '2'}">Goto2</a>
```

In the compoents ngOnInit I read the parameter mode and the compnent acts beause of that.

```
ngOnInit (
{
    this.mode = this.rt.snapshot.queryParams ["mode"];
    ...
```

But because the router does only act if the URL changes the component will not get a reload.

How can I handle that the best way with using only one compoent with parameters??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to subscribe to queryParams

```
this.rt.queryParams.subscribe((queryparams) => {
        this.mode= queryparam['mode'];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The Angular router does reuse your component, because the url (RouterConfig) is the same (You can change behavior via [RouteReuseStrategy](https://medium.com/@juliapassynkova/angular-2-component-reuse-strategy-9f3ddfab23f5)) subscribe on activatedRoute.queryParams to get the params.

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // subscribe to router event
    this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
        let userId = params['mode'];
        console.log(mode);
      });
  }
```